# Use Google App Engine as a reverse proxy to my local server

Tags: google-app-engine, dotcloud

**Background**

Before dotCloud decides to shut down its free sandbox service, I used it as sort of a reverse proxy to reroute all requests to a particular domain, to a local server of mine in which I'm hosting a Mono based application (.NET 3.5 web app running on a Cent-OS Linux). Essentially, the domain forwarded the requests to my dotCloud app and the app, through SSH, to my local server.

**Question**

I wonder if similar setup is possible with Google App Engine. Any help is appreciated.

**More Information**

I got the idea from [here](http://blog.dotcloud.com/open-your-local-webapp-to-the-web-with-dotclo). My dotCloud app is nothing but a Nginx configuration file that forwards all http(s) requests to a SSH port that was bound to a local port (which I configured for my web server to use).

As for my motive, well, I bought a host service with PHP stack and later on decided not to use PHP. So in order to avoid another purchase I used dotCloud.